# cassandra ring is disturbed after upgrade

Tags: cassandra

I have 6 nodes in my cassandra cluster. Now I have upgraded cluster from cassandra 0.8.7 to release version of cassandra 1.1.

Now nodetool ring shows positions of all the nodes are disturbed.Previously it was in order starting from node1 to node6.
Is there any solution for this?

Nodetool ring of my cluster gives following result

```
Address    Rack        Status State   Load            Owns    Token

node1      rack1       Up     Normal  300.27 GB       16.67%  0
node5      rack1       Up     Normal  227.63 GB       16.67%  113427455640312821154458202477256070484
node6      rack2       Up     Normal  343.19 GB       16.67%  141784319550391026443072753096570088105
node2      rack2       Up     Normal  211.45 GB       16.67%  28356863910078205288614550619314017621
node3      rack1       Up     Normal  252.83 GB       16.67%  56713727820156410577229101238628035242
node4      rack2       Up     Normal  239.85 GB       16.67%  85070591730234615865843651857942052863
```

Comment: Does that cause any issue? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just sorting them using a string sort on the token, not an integer sort.  Should probably be reported to the [Cassandra JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA) as an issue (as it is confusing), but it won't cause a problem.

**Update:** Should be fixed in the latest 1.1 builds. [CASSANDRA-3863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3863)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see the nodetool ring is ordering it's cluster details by token. This will not cause any problems at all.